# ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null

Tags: powershell

I have this power shell script which read the Office 365 logs for 2 sharepoint sites and generate a csv file:-

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your tenant password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "O365.key"

#Get the script path

$dir = ""

#Get the current date

$date = (Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy-hhmmss)

#Store the outputfile

$CSVFile = "$dir\Auditlogs_$date.csv"

#Details for sending email

$From = "*****@*****.com"

$To = "*****@*****.com"

$CC ="*****@*****.com"

$smtp = "outlook.office365.com"

$Subject = "Sharepoint audit logs"

#Whom to notify incase of connection to exchange online module fails. This will be the task owner.

$notify="*****@*****.com"

$Body = "Hi Team, Please find the audit logs for the following sharepoint sites for the last x days.

Thanks, O365 Team "

#Create a backup folder and move all the old files to it.

$destination = "$dir\Backup"

$Move = Get-ChildItem -Path "$dir\Auditlogs_*.csv" #| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1

foreach ($file in $Move) {

  $parent = Split-Path $file.FullName -Parent

  Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $destination -Force

}

#store the o365 credentials

$TenantUname = "*****@*****.com"

#Run the following single line to store the password of account that will be used to connect to o365 exchange online

#Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your tenant password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "foldername\O365.key"

#Replace the o365 key file that you stored the password.

$TenantPass = $TenantPass = cat "O365.key" | ConvertTo-SecureString

$TenantCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $TenantUname,$TenantPass

#make sure the exchangeonline module is installed. The script will fail if module not installed.

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

try { Connect-ExchangeOnline #-UseWebLogin #-Credential $TenantCredentials } catch [System.Exception] { $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message

          $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName

          $WebReqErr = $error[0] | Select-Object * | Format-List -Force

  Write-Error "An error occurred while attempting to connect to the requested service.  $ErrorMessage"

  Send-MailMessage -From $From -To  $notify -SmtpServer $smtp -Subject "Failed to connect to exchnage online" -Body "Please check ." }

#list of sharepoint sites (* means all sub sites as well)

$SiteURLs = @("https://m******.sharepoint.com/sites/*",

"https://m*******.sharepoint.com/sites/hr-hr/*")

#List of audit logs

#For a list of audit logs, refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#file-and-page-activities

$Operations = @('PageViewed','FileAccessed','FileDownloaded','FileDeleted')

#audit logs for 1 days from today's date

$startDate=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

#Number of iterations ()

$daysToSkip=3

$endDate=Get-Date #today's date

#iteration start for 3 days

     while ($startDate -lt $endDate) {
        $startdate1=$startDate

        $startDate = $startDate.AddDays($daysToSkip)

        $enddate1=$startDate

$FileAccessLog = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startDate1
-EndDate $EndDate1 -Operations $Operations -ResultSize 5000 -ObjectIds $SiteURLs

$FileAccessLog.auditdata | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP | `

   Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
        }

   if ((import-csv $CSVFile).Length -gt 0)    {
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -SmtpServer $smtp -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Attachments $CSVFile }
```

But i am getting this error:-

[image]

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:10 char:28
+ $FileAccessLog.auditdata | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object CreationT ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Comment: I do not see any question? You are trying to run ConverTo-Json on a null value. You need to add proper handling to make sure that there is something to convert.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, you're pipelining your variable `$FileAccessLog.auditdata` to `ConvertFrom-Json` but its value is null, or nothing inside. It's clearly as per the error description.

Here's how you read PowerShell error (in case you see once again).
[image]

1. The underlined statement is the one throwing error.
2. See and analyze what's the error.
3. Look where (which line and characters) it threw the error.